# Downloading a file from ftp server while file is being altered/overwritten

Tags: java, ftp, stream

We're downloading a file from FTP server. Content of the file changes sometimes. File name is always the same.

Is this scenario possible?

1. File content is "aaaaaaaaaaaaa"
2. We start downloading
3. File is overwritten and it looks like "bbbbbbbbbbbbb"
4. File content we get is "aaaaabbbbbbb"

Library used for downloading is apache commons-net.

Code used is:

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
//client connecting code...
//...
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ftpClient.retrieveFile(path, outputStream);
outputStream.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(new File("myFile.txt")));
```

Comment: The FTP should make sure that this never happens.

Comment: If that is possible, it's the FTP servers fault and you cannot do anything about it on the client side.

Comment: as a side note, you should almost never use ByteArrayOutputStream when dealing with arbitrary files.  you are just asking to run out of memory.  you should just pass your FileOutputStream to the `retrieveFile()` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can actually happen. So I would suggest you to get a checksum of the file before downloading. (Use FTP site command to execute scripts on server to give you the checksum) and then after downloading, compare with the checksum of the downloaded file.

Comment: I never used SITE command. I only have access through FTP. I can not upload scripts to FTP server. Is there a way to calculate checksum without scripts?

Comment: If you can't have the FTP Admin install scripts on your behalf, the other thing that can be done is to check the timestamp before and after the transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the scenario is possible, depending on how the FTP server is implemented, and how files are being written to the area it is serving up.

There is nothing that you can do at the FTP client / protocol level to deal with this.

But you can address it at the application level by having the server-side application generate and write a checksum or hash of the updated file and write it to the FTP area as well.  The client can then read the data file and the checksum file, and check that the checksum of the data file is correct.  If they don't match, the remedy is to fetch the two files again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using unix server, files should never change in progress of downloading. There is nothing you can do against change after connection interruption. But to not change files being downloaded, you should change process uploading or creating files to FTP server. First upload file into temporary file name. I use $RANDOM in bash, it does not really matter, .tmp suffix would be enough, as long as in the same directory does not exist also samename.tmp as legal files. Then do mv tempname.tmp samename. Move is on unix servers atomic operations. That means users that started will continue to download original file. Users that will open file after move will start to download new file instead. Old file will be deleted by kernel when all handles opened by FTP server were closed.

Comment: I have no access to FTP server.